# Changing the color of specific xticks in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm looking for a way to change the color of specific xtick values on my plot. 
For example, I have all my current xtick labels as black, however I want the xtick values at 7,11,12,14,18,25,26 all to be the color red, while leaving every other xtick label as black.

Is there a possible way to do this?

Comment: Please provide some diagrammatic details for the same to help us get clear picture of your problem!!

Comment: Ticklines are just standard4 `Line2D` objects, so you can just set their color directly. What are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pull back the line2d objects that display the ticks, and change their color based on their location.  You will need to filter the ticklines to only include the displayed ticks (seems to be indicated by the marker).

```
ax = plt.gca()
for t, loc in zip(filter(lambda x: x.get_marker()==3, ax.xaxis.get_ticklines()), 
                ax.xaxis.get_ticklocs()):
    if loc in (7,11,12,14,18,25,26):
        print(f'Changing tick line at {loc} to red')
        t.set_color('red')
```

Comment: honestly, beautiful!   :)